# Activity changed animation with SingleTask and ClearTask intent

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin.android

I have `LoginActivity` and `MainActivity` in my application.
I need to remove `LoginActivity` from backstack when user successfully logs in, `MainActivity` when user logouts. 
Therefore I have added `ClearTask` and `SingleTask` intent flags for `MainActivity` and `LoginActivity`.

That works as expected but it has raised another problem - I lost custom animations registered with `overridePendingTransitions(int, int)`.

Is there any way to setup custom animations with `SingleTask` and `ClearTask` intent?
Is it possible to achieve activity workflow I have described before with custom animations?

Comment: make a BaseActivity which is extended by all the activities and let it do the handling of animation for you.

Comment: @Dr.aNdRO and how that would override default android activity switch animation?

Answer (score 1):

When you navigate user from LoginActivty to MainActivity you just have to call finish(); after your intent activity navigation code. You can add activity animation in main theme style.

In you main application theme. Add following :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
   <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/OutdoorTheme.Window</item>
</style> 

<style name="OutdoorTheme.Window" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity">
    <item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/abc_fade_in</item>
    <item name="android:activityOpenExitAnimation">@anim/abc_fade_out</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/abc_fade_in</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseExitAnimation">@anim/abc_fade_out</item>
</style>
```

abc_fade_in.xml

```
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
   android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
   android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
```

abc_fade_out.xml

```
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
   android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
   android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
```

Comment: that unfortunately does not work for SingleTask and ClearTask. I can not simply call .Finish in case of MainActivity back to LoginActivity because back stack could have other activies than MainActivity. Logout is available from activity which is launched by MainActivity (i have to clear backstack).